# Inserting my pdf in my blogs

Tags: jekyll, cloudcannon

I have a posts page which stores every individual blog. And each blog has a pdf file. I can upload the pdf via the blog page but when I execute my code through the for-loop on posts - post.file_doucment_path it just shows the pdf file location.  Do I need to add a seperate js pdf reader package to get it working? Cheers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

HTML5 `<object>` element can embed PDFs in a page without an external library.

`<object data="the.pdf" width="1000" height="1000" type='application/pdf'/>`

Just replace "`the.pdf`" with your file document path with Jekyll syntax.

e.g.
`<object data="{{ post.file_document_path }}" width="1000" height="1000" type='application/pdf'/>`

Comment: Don't forget to close the object tag. Correct syntax is `<object ...></object>`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element