# jekyll won't render text after pdf is embedded into an article

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I have the following in an article

```
---
id: 1001
title: 'Cost of Self-Hosting a VPN server in AWS'
date: 2019-07-09T15:49:03-04:00
---

Some text

<object data="/assets/uploads/2019/07/09/Aws-Bill-Jun2019.pdf" width="1000" height="1000" type='application/pdf' />

Some more text
```

Now jekyll correctly renders the initial text block as well as the PDF but the text after the pdf isn't rendered, nor is the footer and navigation.

I don't want to be doing any self promotion but you [can see this in action here](https://blog.nikhilbhardwaj.in/2019/07/09/self-hosted-vpn-aws-cost/). If you view the page source then there are a couple of paragraphs after the pdf, these don't show up on the page.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105960/inserting-my-pdf-in-my-blogs), to embed the PDF. Are there some issues when an `object` is embedded into the page along with markdown, i.e. markdown is mixed with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<object>` [closing tag is mandatory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object).

> **Tag omission**  : None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.

This will resolve your problem.

```
<object 
  data="/assets/uploads/2019/07/09/Aws-Bill-Jun2019.pdf" 
  width="1000" 
  height="1000" 
  type="application/pdf"></object>
```